# tensorflow installation on gpu in ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

pip3 install tensorflow-gpu --user

whenever I run the above command I usually get this message;

```
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools<=39.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (39.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.4.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.1.6 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.31.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow-gpu) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow-gpu) (2.6.11)
```

and when I goto python3 and import tensorflow as tf;
I get the following errors:

ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you follow complete tensorflow installation instructions? Install CUDA/CUDNN first and make sure you update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable with the location of the cuda libraries.

Comment: Yes here is my path for cuda env.         export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

Comment: Use cuda 9.0. Precompiled tensorflow looks for 9.0. If you want to use 9.2, build tensorflow from source. Also run 'env' command to make sure you have correct path components separated by ":"

Comment: thanks for your ecomment: I have echoed ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} and it gives me this info:/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.222/linux/tbb/lib/intel64_lin/gcc4.7:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.222/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.222/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin

Comment: pip3 show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/asad.ullah/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: protobuf, gast, tensorboard, termcolor, grpcio, absl-py, setuptools, wheel, numpy, six, astor
Required-by:

Comment: What @swiftg is saying is that you must follow "EXACTLY" the steps, including the "EXACT VERSIONS". Anything different will break the installation.

Comment: The most important part is: *install cuda 9.0*, I have already gone through this problem twice.

Comment: I can not have access to sudo. Can cuda 9.0 be installed without sudo command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact problem. I uninstalled tensorflow and followed the steps mentioned in the link below and it worked:
http://www.python36.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-9-2-for-python-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it possible to install TF without root or sudo?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. But, I'm not sure about the outcome of your programs. You might bump into some access related issues for CUDA or something else. If you found my answer to be useful and it fixed your problems, kindly accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: for 9.1 cuda you can directly compile tensorflow without going for making a bazel source using the following command:                                                  
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu